# MPMusicPlayerController not working first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmusicplayercontroller

I have implemented MPMusicPlayerController playing song functionality in the app. Everything working fine but very first time of launching the app is not working.Second time onwards it is working awesome. **What I understood is setNowPlayingItem is not setting on first time**. Any ideas/suggestions could be very helpful. Thanks for your valuable time.

**Code**

```
    MPMediaItemCollection *collection = [[MPMediaItemCollection alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:selectedMediaItem1, nil]];

    [appDelegate.musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:collection];

    [appDelegate.musicPlayer setNowPlayingItem:selectedMediaItem1];

    [appDelegate.musicPlayer prepareToPlay];

    [appDelegate.musicPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug! I opened a Technical Support Incident about this. We hope in iOS 10. Music and apple music will likely have a big update.

Comment: How did your support go? Was it reproducible enough to fix?

Answer (score -1):

you should also set a currentPlaybackTime for your player,

```
   // Restore the now-playing item and its current playback time.
    appDelegate.musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem      = nowPlayingItem;
    appDelegate.musicPlayer.currentPlaybackTime = currentPlaybackTime;
```

Check this link for more details:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/UsingMediaPlayback/UsingMediaPlayback.html

Comment: Did you set it to 0?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I have set it